# Is it possible to match another element by an attribute of the current element?

Tags: html, css, sass

Let's assume we have a checkbox. and we want to show dependent on the checkbox-checked state different elements somewhere else.

---

#### Note

And keep in mind the checkbox and its attributes like the id are dynamic and are not known at "compile" time, thus there is no way SCSS can use it.

I use `test` only to demonstrate the use-case not the actual implementation.

---

example:

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="test" name="try_me" value="0" />
<div>
    <div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div data-id="test">
            checkbox is checked content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
</div>
```

is it possible to target the div by an input attribute like the id?

example:

```scss
input[type="checkbox"] {
    ~ div *:has([data-id=(attr(id))]) {
        background-color: red;     
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

I tried everything from `attr` to `has`, all CSS functionality is not enough to handle such a case.

Answer (score 2):

If you apply a wrapper around this, you can listen for the checked input like this and apply a style to your content:

```css
.wrapper:has(input:checked) .content {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="checkbox">


  <div class="content">
    content
  </div>
</div>
```

Also works for multiple checkboxes, just add ids to the checkboxes.

```css
.wrapper:has(#test1:checked) .test1 {
  display: block;
  background: green;
}

.wrapper:has(#test2:checked) .test2 {
  display: block;
  background: red;
}

.content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="checkbox" id="test1">
  <input type="checkbox" id="test2">


  <div class="content test1">
    content 1
  </div>

  <div class="content test2">
    content 2
  </div>

</div>
```

Otherwise I think you'll be looking for a javascript function where you'd listen to a change on the checkbox, get the target id and add a style to the target content.

Here is the really simple JS solution:

```js
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]")

for (let checkbox of checkboxes) {
  checkbox.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    if (e.target.checked) document.querySelector("." + e.target.id).classList.add("show");
    else document.querySelector("." + e.target.id).classList.remove("show");
  })
}
```

```css
.content {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="test1">
<input type="checkbox" id="test2">


<div class="content test1">
  content 1
</div>

<div class="content test2">
  content 2
</div>
```

Comment: yes this would work if you only have one/multiple generic input fields, but im looking for a solution where i can target a "linked" element.

Comment: @Champignon I don't think this will work with CSS only unless you setup your layout accordingly and put checkbox and content into one wrapper. I added the JS solution too, probably the easiest way to achieve what you want.

Comment: i guess your right, this is only possible with javascript. and no i cannot change the html layout, its very complex and deeply nested.

Comment: way easier to do it that way, just make sure you use the right selector to loop through the checkboxes that actually trigger content. probably best to use a css class for that.